# Filter list with Linq and lookupvalue

Tags: sharepoint-online, linq

I've a list with a lookup column named **Agents**.

I want to filter it by using the Lookup Value in "Agents" with Linq but I don't understand how to be able to compare the lookup Value to a string.

the code looks like this now:

```
var filteredConnectList = connectItems.Where(u => u.FieldValues["Agent"].ToString().ToLower() == user.FieldValues["NameAndMail"].ToString().ToLower()).ToList();
```

`u.FieldValues["Agents"]` returns an object of FieldLookupValue I suppose but I need to access the lookup Value in that object.

Some help would be nice here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula:

```
var filteredConnectList = connectItems.Where(u => ((FieldLookupValue) u.FieldValues["Agent"]) == user.FieldValues["NameAndMail"].ToString().ToLower()).ToList();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunate not, this is made in CSOM code so the SPFieldLookupValue does not exist and FieldLookupValue does not have a constructor thats takes arguments

Comment: Please verify if this works, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nope. I've already tried that casting.

Comment: Please verify if this works, I've updated my answer. May be this should work.

Comment: Yes I missed that paranthesis around the whole casting.. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
var filteredConnectList = connectItems.Where(u => u.FieldValues["Agent"] != null &&
            (new SPFieldLookupValueCollection(u => u.FieldValues["Agent"].ToString())).OfType<SPFieldLookupValue>()
            .Where(v => v.LookupValue.ToString().ToLower() == user.FieldValues["NameAndMail"].ToString().ToLower()).ToList();
```

Please let me know if any question on this.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this is still a client application so there are no SP_nnnnnn objects availible. the SPFieldLookupValueCollection for example and it seens that there are no equvalent CSOM object for that.